# Open and pass values from DataGrid to Form by CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a CheckBox column in every record. So, what i want is that when i click on the checkbox, all the information of that row go to a form where i can make some editions in the information of the record.
My problem is how can I pass the info from the DGV to a form, only by clicking on the checkbox column.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
 private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.GetType()==typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            && (bool)(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value)==true)
          {
                Form2 x =new Form2();
                x.label1.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
                x.Show ();
          }

        }
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works, more or less. the code gives me what i want, there's just a problem when i close the form with de DGV, FORM2 opens again! i think that's because the state change when i close the form with the dgv

Comment: @Reznor13. May be This Event occures again. put the break point and check.

Comment: the event only occures once. i think i should define the type as true

Comment: do you open the form again in anywhere? @Reznor13

Comment: no, that form only opens in this context. i really think that's a problem with the state, because when i uncheck the checkbox, the form opens again. The event doesn't understand checked/unchecked, it only understands that the checkbox state has changed... am i seeing it right? :)

Comment: I dont know how to make it:\ i wrote:
if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.GetType()==typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) && dataGridView1.CurrentCell = true) but i't doesnt appear to be right :\

Comment: when i do the click on the checkbox i get the NullReferenceException :\